# Joining in SQL on more than 2 tables Using ORACLE

Tags: sql, join

Suppose I have three tables, A, B and C.
I did Join on table A and table B, now I wanted to do Join on result AB and table c.
Do I need to create view and then do Join or need to do it by Nested query?

Comment: What about joining ViEW AB on table c and using nested queries?

Answer (score 7):

You don't say which DB you're using, so the syntax could be wrong, but multi-table joins aren't any different, really, than joining two tables:

```
SELECT ...
FROM a
JOIN b ON ...
JOIN c ON ...
JOIN d ON ...
```

Comment: Also worth nothing with respect to inner joins anyway that ((a join b) join c) = (a join b join c)

Answer (score 4):

No, you will do it as follows

```
SELECT  *
FROM    A [INNER/LEFT/RIGHT/OUTER] JOIN
        B   ON  [a/b].IDCols = [a/b].IDCols [INNER/LEFT/RIGHT/OUTER] JOIN
        C   ON  [a/b/c].IDCols = [a/b/c].IDCols
```

The specific joins (INNER/LEFT/RIGT/OUTER) will depend on what your requirements are.

Have a look at [Introduction to JOINs – Basic of JOINs](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/) for an overview

The criteria for the `JOIN ON`s will also depend on how the tables relate to one another.

Comment: The C join can also include table B in the ON clause... a.IDCols = c.IDCols AND b.IDCols = c.IDCols.

Comment: Yes, that is tru, that is why I specified *The criteria for the JOIN ONs will also depend on how the tables relate to one another*

Answer (score 0):

You can either use something like this:

```
select *
from A, B, C
where A.id = B.id
and A.id = C.id
```

or you can use something like this:

```
select *
from A INNER JOIN B ON (A.id = B.id)
       INNER JOIN C ON (A.id = C.id)
```

How you join will of course depend on how the tables relate to each other, so what's the primary key and foreign key of A,B,C.
You might also use OUTER JOIN instead of INNER JOIN, depending on our data.